# Strange initialization in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I've heard I can initialize a value using this syntax:

```
int foo = {5};
```

Also, I can do the same thing using even less code:

```
int foo{5};
```

Well, are there any advantages/disadvantages of using them? Is it a good practice, or maybe it's better to use standard: ?

```
int foo = 5;
```

Comment: It's called uniform initialization syntax. For primitive types such as `int` it is no better/worse, advantageous/disadvantageous than using simple assignment, or parentheses in place of the braces. For user defined types, using `T foo{U};` to initialize `foo` avoids the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three examples you gave, are not quite the same. Uniform initialization (the ones with `{ }`) does not allow narrowing conversions

```
int i = 5.0;   // Fine, stores 5
int i{5.0};    // Won't compile!
int i = {5.0}; // Won't compile!
```

Furthermore, copy initializations (the ones with an `=`) do not allow explicit constructors.

The new C++11 feature uniform initialization and its cousin initializer-lists (which generalizes the brace initialization syntax to e.g. the standard containers) is a tricky animal with many quirks. The most vexing parse mentioned in the comments by @Praetorian is only one of them, tuples and multidimensional arrays are another pandora's box.

Comment: It compiles just [fine](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1Dqy2I$3), though with warnings.

Comment: @Haroogan that is why you always need to compile with -Wall -Werror. BTW, CLang gives an error.

Comment: @NicolBolas Read 8.5.4/3 that has the example `int x2 {2.0}; // error: narrowing`. It is an error.

Comment: @NicolBolas Furthermore, 8.5.4/7 states that "A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion — from a ﬂoating-point type to an integer type". Actually, only double-to-float, large-integer-to-small-integer and integer-to-floating-point have the "representation is possible" exception to them, but floating-to-integer does not.